# Calling function name inside function

Tags: javascript, greatest-common-divisor

There are some concept I still cannot figure out in Javascript. Like this one for example. I came across this code while searching for a function to return the greatest common divisor of two integers. I tested it but I can't understand how this returns the gcd. Please can explain anyone who understand explain what does  `return gcd(b, a % b);` do here?

```
    var gcd = function(a, b) {
    if ( ! b) {
        return a;
    }
    return gcd(b, a % b);
};
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a recusion, which is a pattern of calling the same function again with different paramters until an exit condition is found and then the recursion stops.

```
// exit condition
if (!b) {
    return a;
}
```

In this case the function is called again with moved parameter `b` as `a` and a new parameter of `b` with `a` modulo `b`.

```
// call function again with different parameters
return gcd(b, a % b);
```

Comment: What does *"Use a named function, not an anonymous function"* have to do with the question being asked?